# Web Services Interoperability

Tags: java, wcf, web-services

I have few fundamental questions

Question#1

- With WCF you can expose a service as HTTP/TCP/MSMQ binding
- Similar to this do we have any equivalent solution in Java platform for exposing service with different bindings

Question #2

- i have worked on .NET 2.0 ASMX service and consumed the same using .NET client
- What are interoperability aspects that we need to consider if I need to consume this service with Java client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question #1:

- WCF can expose service on multiple transports but only HTTP(S) is interoperable
- Java APIs also can expose SOAP service over different transport. For example SOAP services can be exposed over JMS. JAX-WS has extensibility points to provide [custom transports](http://blogs.oracle.com/oleksiys/entry/how_to_create_custom_network). It is all about APIs because SOAP is independent on the transport (in contrast to REST which works only over HTTP).

Question #2:

- ASMX services can conform to WS-I Basic Profile 1.1 which is considered as interoperability minimum. I guess all Java SOAP APIs can consume these services.